# ruby, purpose of string replace method

Tags: ruby

From the [online ruby documentation][1] of the replace method of the string class:

replace (other_str) → str
Replaces the contents and taintedness of str with the corresponding values in other_str.

```
s = "hello"         #=> "hello"
s.replace "world"   #=> "world"
```

#### Questions:

1) what does it mean "taintedness"? 
2) what is the purpose of such a method? Why using it instead of simply `s = "world"` ? The only idea that I have has to do with pointers, but I don't know how this subject is handled in ruby and if this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that this has something to do with pointers. `s = "world"` would construct a new object and assign `s` a pointer to that object. Whereas `s.replace "world"` modifies the string object that `s` already points to.

One case where `replace` would make a difference is when the variable isn't directly accessible:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :x
  def initialize
    @x = ""
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

foo.x = "hello"       # this won't work. we have no way to assign a new pointer to @x
foo.x.replace "hello" # but this will
```

`replace` has nothing in particular to do with taintedness, the documentation is just stating that it handles tainted strings properly. There are better answers for explaining that topic: [What are the Ruby's Object#taint and Object#trust methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165664/what-are-the-rubys-objecttaint-and-objecttrust-methods)

Comment: Very nice answer, Max. AgostinoX, you may want to also look at [Array#replace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-replace), [Set#replace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-replace) and [Hash#replace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-replace). Other classes may have the method also.