# Couldn't understand how the command line option "-T" is used in practice

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

Couldn't understand how the command line option below is used in practice.

```
-T[level=1]
```

I tried this code:

```
#commandoptionstest.rb
puts "hello world"
```

with various `SAFE` levels:

Output is OK

```
@ubuntu:~/script$ ruby -x commandoptionstest.rb
# => hello world
```

Why the error? What do I need to do in `commandoptionstest.rb` to allow `-x` with `-T`?

```
@ubuntu:~/script$ ruby -x -T commandoptionstest.rb
# => ruby: no -x allowed in tainted mode (SecurityError)
```

Output is coming

```
@ubuntu:~/script$ ruby -T commandoptionstest.rb
# => hello world
```

Output is coming

```
@ubuntu:~/script$ ruby -T1 commandoptionstest.rb
# => hello world
```

Output is coming

```
@ubuntu:~/script$ ruby -T2 commandoptionstest.rb
# => hello world
```

Output is coming

```
@ubuntu:~/script$ ruby -T3 commandoptionstest.rb
# => hello world
```

Again why the error?

```
@ubuntu:~/script$ ruby -T4 commandoptionstest.rb
# => commandoptionstest.rb:15:in `write': Insecure operation `write' at level 4 (SecurityError)
#   from commandoptionstest.rb:15:in `puts'
#   from commandoptionstest.rb:15:in `puts'
#   from commandoptionstest.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

With the help of the above code, could you please explain why the `SAFE` levels `1`, `2`, `3` are printing `"hello world"`, while `SAFE` level `4` not? To allow the write operations at `SAFE` level `4`, what should be done here?

Comment: Did you not look at the question you duplicated?

Comment: @hd1 IMO it's not a dupe, since `-T` affects more than object tainting.

Comment: Please stop voting to close as a duplicate: it is not. The linked question asks specifically about tainting objects. The `-T` command line option sets the Ruby interpreter's `$SAFE` level, which does a *lot* more than simply defining whether or not, and which, and when objects are tainted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sets the `$SAFE` level.

This dictates how inputs are handled, along with a great number of other things regarding environment variables, I/O, threads, exceptions, interpreter command line args, etc.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html

IMO the docs are a good place to start. If you have a question about a *specific* behavior, ask.

---

To address your comment and your edits:

Yes, I can, but **the docs can too**, and likely better.

**Why does `-x` not work?**

Because the docs say it won't:

> **$SAFE >= 1**
>      * The command-line options -e, -i, -I, -r, -s, -S, and -x are not allowed.

[~]$ ruby --help
Usage: ruby [switches] [--] [programfile] [arguments]
  # elided
  -T[level=1]     turn on tainting checks

So the default level if `-T` is specified with no number is `1`, which means `$SAFE >= 1`, which means exactly what the docs say: `-x` is not allowed.

**Why doesn't `puts` work?**

Difficult to say since you don't actually provide the code you're executing, but most likely, again, as the docs say:

> **$SAFE >= 4**
>      * Can't write to files or pipes.

Comment: can it be possible to show with IRB type small snippets to see what level affects how with the `-T` option using in the code?

Comment: @user2060534 An exhaustive example would be hundreds of lines long--IMO a complete answer is out of scope. Please look at the documentation provided and narrow your question down to specific behaviors--the bullet point list includes over three dozen specific behaviors.

Comment: actually what confusing me is - I want to see say -  if I don't   define `SAFE` level as `2` - then what would happen and if define then how then it guarantees safety?

Comment: @user2060534 ... The behaviors are characterized in the documentation I linked to. The interpreter handles the various `$SAFE` levels.

Comment: actually the other options of command-line I tried in my console and understood how they works and this is the one I can't tested that way :(

Comment: @user2060534 Of course you can; that makes no sense. Many of the listed behaviors are trivially testable. *Try* some of the behaviors, like making a directory at `-T2`. Read the bullets.

Comment: @user2060534 Sure. See the updated answer. Please consider actually reading the link I provided, which answers your questions.

Comment: What I need to do in the  commandoptionstest.rb file to allow -x with -T?

Comment: @user2060534 Uh... **YOU CAN'T**. If `$SAFE >= 1` then `-x` is **not an allowed command line parameter**. There is no other way to say this than that.

Answer (score 0):

[The perl CGI FAQ](http://gunther.web66.com/FAQS/taintmode.html) does a much better job of explaining this than I could. Basically, it's a way to ensure your parameters have been validated by you.

Comment: Only partially useful for Ruby, though, since a lot of what happens is Ruby- and safe-level specific.

Comment: A [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736161/whats-the-purpose-of-tainting-ruby-objects), nevertheless

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree with you. The question he marked is not fully answered by my question.

Comment: @hd1 I disagree, because the question asks about more than object tainting, it asks about what behavior is affected by `-T` (i.e., `$SAFE`), and that covers a lot more ground.

Comment: Then I clearly misunderstood the scope of his question, my apologies

Comment: Apparently, it's a [system feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

Comment: @user2060534 No, you cannot un-vote. The comments and answer will likely be enough to forestall additional dupe votes (unless there's a different dupe question).